# exec() not executing the complete command in php

Tags: php, linux, exec, ps

I am writing a php script that fetch the details of a background process using the "ps" command on linux.

The ps command has various switches but i have issue with exec() on executing the -o switch

#### The flow

- Create a new background process and get it`s PID
- Pull specific details of the process using the -o switch on ps command
- Kill the process

#### The Code

```php
    function create_and_kill()
    {
        // Create a new background process and get it`s PID
        $process = BackgroundProcess::create("Command Goes here");
        $display = "\nProcess ID: $process";
        sleep(1);

        // Pull specific details of the process using the -o on ps command
        $result = [];
        exec("ps -p $process -o pid,user,%cpu,%mem,start,time,command", $result);
        $display .= "\n\n".implode("\n",$result);
        sleep(1);

        // Kill the process
        $display .= "\n".shell_exec("kill -9 $process");

        return nl2br($display);
    }
```

#### The Result

> Process ID: 17842
>
> PID TTY TIME CMD
> 17842 pts/0 00:00:00 php

The result should be something like this:

> Process ID: 17842
>
> PID USER     %CPU %MEM  STARTED     TIME COMMAND
> 17842 username  0.2  0.3 18:27:47 00:00:01 [command]

I guess somehow only "ps -p $process" was executed and negleting the -o switch and the rest of the command and the built-in server console of php returns this "sh: 2: -o: not found".

i have tried combining -p with -o so i write it like so:

```sh
ps -po 12342 pid,%cpu
```

Yet it doesnt work

Please i need help

Comment: Are you certain that the `$process` variable contains a number (the pid)?

Comment: @ZoliSzabó Yes it displayed the Process id on the first line, In the result and it also show some informations, meaning the process exist

Comment: I can't replicate that behaviour in an interactive php shell.  ` $result=[]; exec( "ps -p 3781682 -o pid,user,%cpu,%mem,start,time,command", $result); print $result[1];` renders `3781682 tink    0.2  0.5   Apr 30 00:23:34 /usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox` ... did you somehow manage to tack a `;` on to the pid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still wondering about what I said in my comment; if you changed the order of the parameters, what do you get?

```
        exec("ps -o pid,user,%cpu,%mem,start,time,command -p $process", $result);
```

Comment: You mean it worked fine on your side ?

actually when i run it on the terminal it worked fine but work work in exec, but i will have to try what you suggested

Comment: @IlesanmiOlawaleAdedotun As I said, that code snippet in an interactive php session (CLI, `php -a`, using variables and all) it works as designed, for me the order didn't make a difference.

Comment: Wow it worked, But do you think it doesnt matter ?

Comment: when i placed the -o switch first it worked

Comment: It doesn't matter **here** ... which makes me point you at my question in the comments above.  Does the PID in your variable contain a semicolon?

Comment: No it doesn`t at all.. infact i have to make the ``` BackgroundProcess::create();``` save the PID in a file and retrieve it again just to make sure its getting the clean PID...

however my worry now is that i cant still get to the bottom of this.

Comment: That's odd ... a semicolon sneaking in there (or a `&&` ) would explain that the shell treats `-o` as a new command.

Comment: Yeah it treated it like a new command... I will go with your solution for now because your solution is still valid and but to avoid issue in the future later when the system is done I will inspect the error closely...